Server-side datatable implementation: how to read the date in dd/mm/yy format from the controller for search
As the title suggests, I am implementing server-side datatable.
I have a problem with the global search to read birthDate in dd/mm/yy format.
I can only read the date in y-m-d format (i.e. the default date of the db).
This is my code:


        // get data from user_dummies table
        $query = DB::table('user_dummies')->select('*');

        // Global Search
        $search = $request->search;
        $query = $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->orWhere('firstName', 'like', "%" . $search . "%");
            $query->orWhere('lastName', 'like', "%" . $search . "%");
            $query->orWhere('age', 'like', "%" . $search . "%");
            $query->orWhere('birthDate', 'like', "%" . $search . "%");
            $query->orWhere('role', 'like', "%" . $search . "%");
        });



I tried to write the code corresponding to the birthDate put below but I get an error from Datatable,
i.e. DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Ajax error.


 $query->orWhere(date('d/m/y',strtotime('birthDate')), 'like', "%" . $search . "%");



Can someone tell me how to do this?

Dont change the format of your database, but rather the format of the parameter/value in your condition. If date is format date Ymd then change your $search to date Ymd

@Mr.Kenneth Yes yes, in fact my intention was not to change the database format. Thanks a lot for the suggestion anyway

You can use
$query->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '%d/%m/%y') LIKE ?", ["%$search%"]);

And be aware of SQL Injection

Thanks, you helped me a lot. I didn't know DATE_FORMAT
